# Custom URI Scheme link rendering in Lotus Notes

Tags: url, lotus-notes

I have an application which registers a custom URI scheme along the lines of:

```
myapp://action?parameter=value
```

The handler works well, and using Microsoft software, and software deriving functionality from is, urls renders fine if prefixed by the url: scheme, for an end result of:

```
url:myapp://action?parameter=value
```

In Lotus Notes hower this does not work.

Is there an alternative or other method to allow Notes to render my custom URI scheme as a link and pass it on to the underlying system?

Updated 2011-08-24:

Both domino and Notes are of version 8.5 (8.5.2 specifically).

I am primarily interested in getting these links to render in the body of recieved external email.

Comment: What version of Notes?  I'm pretty sure Notes will pass along anything you put in a hotspot to the OS but I haven't tried with any custom ones before.  Can you use file:// to launch your app by file type instead of using myapp:// ?

Comment: The Notes version is 8.5.2 at the moment, I can make it work for an explicit hotspot, but only if that hotspot is explictly defined. In implicit content, such as recieved external email I do not have that control however.

Comment: sorry for asking questions and not getting back. if you want to send me some tests I can forward them to my notes account and see how they look. i think my gmail address is listed in my profile.